# Return Code is:401 ReasonPharse: Unauthorized.

Tags: maven-3, nexus

I started to practice nexus and i have sample java code.
in command prompt, i went to the project path and ran "mvn clean deploy"

```
  <servers>
<server>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

credentials in settings.xml are correct.
below code has been added in POM.xml file.

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Java Releases Nexus Repository</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8018/repository/maven-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Java Snapshot Nexus Repository</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8018/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
 </distributionManagement>
```

but still it showing 401, unauthorized. Can anyone help me into this.

Comment: Have you changed the admin password? The default admin password nexus ships with is "admin123".

Comment: Thanks for the reply....
i've already changed the default password admin123 to admin.
but its not working

Comment: Do you run Maven on the Nexus server? Is the URL of Nexus really `localhost:8018` ?

Comment: Run "mvn help:effective-settings" and "mvn help:effective-pom" to make sure your settings and pom are what you think they are.  If that doesn't solve it, you should post the actual  maven error log here.